# Mysqldb INSERT INTO syntax error in Python

Tags: python, sql, syntax-error, mysql-python

I have an excel file which I am trying to put into mysql. There are 32 fields which I want to extract using the python plugin xlrd and put into mysql. The data is laid out like so:

[image: Data Layout]

My methodology is to iterate over the rows and columns, adding fieldnames as I go. The code adds the field name but then there is an error when adding the data. (I created the table 'OilProvedReservesHistory' with an index as the only field):

[image: SQL Layout]

```
def get_data_from_sheet(sheet_index, table, start_row, end_row, end_col):

for row in range(start_row - 1, end_row - 1):
    for col in range(end_col):
        cell = sheet.cell(row,col)
        if col == 0:        
            fieldname = cleanup_field(cell.value)
            if fieldname != ("Blank Cell"):
                sql = "ALTER TABLE OilProvedReservesHistory ADD %s VARCHAR(20)" % fieldname
                c.execute(sql)                  
        else:
            data = cleanup_data(cell)
            if data != ("Blank Cell"):
                postToMySQL(data,fieldname,table)


def postToMySQL(data,fieldname,table):
#Generate sql query string                
sql = "INSERT INTO " + table + " ("+ fieldname + ") VALUES %s"
c.execute(sql, data)
# Executes: ("""INSERT INTO OilProvedReservesHistory (US) VALUES 36.533""")

table = create_table_from_sheet_name()

sheet_index = 0
start_row = 5
end_row = 68
end_col = 32

get_data_from_sheet(sheet_index, table, start_row, end_row, end_col)
```

The error I get is:

> _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to  use near ''36.533'' at line 1")

Can you help me get this working? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you simply forgot the parenthesis for your VALUES clause.

```
INSERT INTO OilProvedReservesHistory (US) VALUES (36.533)
```

Try changing your code to:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO " + table + " ("+ fieldname + ") VALUES (%s)"
```

Comment: Ha, yeah you're right! Before I posted this I had been trying to create all the fieldnames first and then post the data values, however I think the error was that I was trying to fill a row with just one value. Thanks!